# NetSuite SuiteScript SSS_CONNECTION_CLOSED

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

Have been getting the SSS_CONNECTION_CLOSED error on https requests within User Event Scripts and suitescript 2.0.  But only on the released versions of the deployments and not if they are in testing. Thought it may be related to tls depreciaation, our server has tls 1.0, 1.1, and 1.2 enabled.

Comment: Are you connecting to a different URL in your released script, as opposed to your testing script?

Comment: Seems to be happening on the testing versions now as well, same url. Working with netsuite support, but enpoint consistantly works in postman so not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Do you mind sharing your code?

Comment: Netsuite recommended implementing a retry mechanism, the request will still fail sometimes but then succeed after retrying once.

Comment: So I assume it doesn't fail every time then?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there were two SuiteScripts deployed for the Sales Order. However, after deleting one of them, the problem was resolved.